# How does one tell when the state of a child window changes in WTL?

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

I've written a simple GUI using WTL:

[image: security center eraser]

I've got everything figured out as far as setting up the window is concerned, and also wired up the menus and such to call whatever I wish. But I need to know when, for example, someone checks one of the checkboxes in the list view, or when someone clicks on a button.

Do these child windows send a message to the main window notifying of the state change, and is that notification generally consistent between child window types?

Comment: If you program in WTL, your best friend is the Spy++. Remember it! :-) (it's a tool that is included in Visual Studio. It isn't installed in the "standard" installation I think)

Comment: @xanatos: What am I supposed to DO with it? :P

Comment: You launch it :-) You launch the app you want to spy. You do Window->Refresh just to be sure. Spy->Log Messages, you use the Finder Tool to "find" your window (normally you select the parent of your control), you begin with all the message select in the Message tab and you do a Ok. Then you'll see that it's capturing 1 million useless messages and you begin disabling them (the WM_MOUSEMOVE, the WM_MOUSELEAVE...) (you can right-click on a message and select Stop Logging Message). You'll discover the world behind the "old" Winapi controls. WPF/Silverlight controls are another world.

Comment: Other possibility (normally better). You start in the "window" window. Window->Refresh. You use the button Find Window. You find a control of your window. Ok. In Property Inspector you click on Synchronize. Now the control is "selected" in the Window window. From there you can look for its parents/childs/siblings, right click on one of them, Messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child notifications are typically sent to the parent window in the form of [`WM_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.

Some child notifications are common across most control types (e.g. `NM_CLICK` and `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`), but in general you'll need to look at the notifications reference for each control type on MSDN to see what's available. To start, the reference for listview notifications are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485962%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the button notifications are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Not universally. Some notifications (mostly the older ones) are sent via `WM_COMMAND`.

Comment: @Billy : The standard listview control supports checkboxes via the [`LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=VS.85).aspx) extended style. I haven't looked at the WTL source, but I assume it's making use of said style rather than doing anything custom.

Comment: I edited /universally/ to /typically/ since there are occasional exceptions, such as `WM_HSCROLL`.